# JOIN VS SUBQUERY

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, correlated-subquery

I need to do this but with a subquery, not a join. My problem is, how can I use a subquery to display another column? I could grab the info from there, but I'll be missing the order_date column from the orders table. Can I use a subquery to display it?

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.customer_first_name, ' ' , c.customer_last_name) AS customer_name, MAX(o.order_date) AS recent_order_date
FROM customers AS c
JOIN orders AS o
ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY customer_name
ORDER BY MAX(o.order_date) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not at all clear what resultset you are trying to return, but it looks an awful like the like the ubiquitous "latest row" problem.

The normative pattern for the solution to that problem is to use a JOIN to the inline view. If there's not a unique constraint, you run the possibility of returning more than one matching row.

To get the latest order (the row in the `orders` table with the maximum `order_date` for each customer, assuming that the `(customer_id, order_date)` tuple is unique, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT o.*
  FROM ( SELECT n.customer_id
              , MAX(n.order_date) AS latest_order_date
           FROM orders n
          GROUP BY n.customer_id
       ) m
  JOIN orders o
    ON o.customer_id = m.customer_id
   AND o.order_date = m.latest_order_date
```

If you want to also retrieve columns from the `customers` table based on the `customer_id` returned from orders, you'd use a JOIN (not a subquery)

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.customer_first_name,' ',c.customer_last_name) AS customer_name
     , c.whatever
     , o.order_date AS recent_order_date
     , o.whatever
  FROM ( SELECT n.customer_id
              , MAX(n.order_date) AS latest_order_date
           FROM orders n
          GROUP BY n.customer_id
       ) m
  JOIN orders o
    ON o.customer_id = m.customer_id
   AND o.order_date = m.latest_order_date
  JOIN customers c
    ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
 ORDER BY o.order_date DESC, o.customer_id DESC
```

---

As I mentioned before, if a given customer can have two orders with the exact same value for `order_date`, there's potential to return more than one order for each `customer_id`.

To rectify that, we can return a unique key from the inline view, and use that in the join predicate to guarantee only a single row returned from orders.

(NOTE: this approach is specific to MySQL, with this syntax, other RDBMS will throw an error that essentially says "the GROUP BY must include all non-aggregates". But MySQL allows it.)

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.customer_first_name,' ',c.customer_last_name) AS customer_name
     , c.whatever
     , o.order_date AS recent_order_date
     , o.whatever
  FROM ( SELECT n.customer_id
              , MAX(n.order_date) AS latest_order_date
              , n.order_id
           FROM orders n
          GROUP BY n.customer_id
       ) m
  JOIN orders o
   AND o.customer_id = m.customer_id
   AND o.order_date = m.latest_order_date
   AND o.order_id = n.order_id
  JOIN customers c
    ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
 ORDER BY o.order_date DESC, o.customer_id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure i understand your question, but i think this works... (not tested though...)

```
SELECT
  (
    SELECT
      CONCAT(c.customer_first_name, ' ' , c.customer_last_name) 
    FROM
      customers c 
    WHERE
      c.customer_id = o.customer_id 
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS customer_name,
  MAX(o.order_date) AS recent_order_date
FROM
  orders o 
GROUP BY 
  customer_name
ORDER BY 
  MAX(o.order_date) DESC
```